# Permanent Drawer

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

Is there a way to make QDrawer shows permanently, and hide the  hamburger icon (in red rectangle)? Or there are other components that could be used for this purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove that `button` from the toolbar and it will show the drawer permanently. The use of the button is just for toggle drawer mini mode.

https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/XWayJWa?editors=1010